# problems with routes laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

After data from a form is saved i wanted to get back to the admin page.
I checked the database and the new data was there but I got an error:
"Route [pages.admin] not defined."

My Admin Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Admin;


class AdminController extends Controller
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation code

        // Saveing code

        return redirect()->route('pages.admin')
                         ->with('success', 'Admins created successfully.');
    }
```

My Page Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controllerpublic 
function admin(){
        return view('pages.admin');
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'PagesController@admin');
Route::post('admin_form', 'AdminController@store');
```

Would appreciate the help.

I looked in online sources but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the name of a view with the name of a route. Your view has the name `pages.admin` because there is a `admin.blade.php` view in the `pages` folder within the `views` folder of your application.

For `route('pages.admin')` to work, you need to assign a name to a route. You may do this by using `name()` when defining your route.

```php
Route::get('/admin', 'PagesController@admin')->name('pages.admin');
```

It is a good practise to always name routes. For example: it allows you to just change the url without having to worry about your redirects breaking, since they use the name that hasn't changed.

Comment: I did as you said and changed route to Route::get('/admin', 'PagesController@admin')->name('pages.admin');
 but it still says "Route [pages.admin] not defined."

Answer (score 0):

I found a video and changed my code in the controller to

```
return redirect('admin');
```

and it worked.